# How to launch add new contact screen in android and iphone with help of HTML with out any server side code?

Tags: android, html, ios, contacts, android-contacts

I want to save the new contact in android phone through local html file with out any server side component.

I have built one html page which has all the information required to build vcard. I want to save that vcard in phone contact list through same html page.

Approach I have tried so far -

1. tel:// - through this href tag - I am able to launch the contact dial screen but I want to launch add contact screen.
2. In android - you can specify intent to launch any app (deep linking?)
   I have tried following hyperlink but it launches Google play store with final result as "Not Found"

"scan" was put in hyperlink because I found one example where scanner app was launched through html. I don't know what should be exact hyperlink to launch add contact screen.

Few examples are present on internet but that are Android Native. I am not sure about exact constant values of those variables in HTML.

Open Contact

3. Build one hyperlink - which downloads the vcard. After file is downloaded - user has to manually open it. Which automatically asks user to save new contact. I just want to avoid this download & opening downloaded file. Is it possible to directly build, save, open local vcard file through javascript?

I have vcf file hosted on my server - when you click on that link - it will be downloaded to your device. When you open it - it will open in add new contact file.

I want to save a new contact in phone contact list through html page. html page is also local to mobile (not on internet)

Actual result is - vcard downloaded through a link is stored in local download folder of android. User has to manually open the file and save the contact.

At least If I can auto open the downloaded vcf file - that will be great. The approach should work in Android & iPhone both.

Answer (score 1):

So here are two useful resources:

1. https://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/modify-data#create-an-intent - explains how to add / edit contacts via intents on Android
2. https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents - explains how to format any Android intent to be launched from a webpage showing in Chrome (note that it'll only work on Chrome/WebView, not alternative browsers)

So you'll want to launch an intent like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intents.Insert.ACTION);
intent.setType(RawContacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
intent.putExtra(Intents.Insert.EMAIL, "hello@world.com");
intent.putExtra(Intents.Insert.PHONE, "+1-212-555-1234");
```

So according to the format in the second article, you'll want to launch something like this:

```
intent://vnd.android.cursor.dir/raw_contact/#Intent;
    action=android.intent.action.INSERT;
    S.email=hello@world.com;
    S.phone=+1-212-555-1234
end;
```

i.e. `<a href="intent://vnd.android.cursor.dir/raw_contact/#Intent;action=android.intent.action.INSERT;S.email=hello@world.com;S.phone=+1-212-555-1234end;">CLICK ME</a>`

And I don't think a similar approach could work on an iPhone, don't think it's possible at all